# Vertical center text using ms-box in IE 10

Tags: internet-explorer, css, sass, flexbox

Here is a mixin to vertically center text in a box

```
@mixin box-center(){
/* Firefox */
  display:-moz-box;
  -moz-box-orient:horizontal;
  -moz-box-pack:center;
  -moz-box-align:center;

/* Safari and Chrome */
  display:-webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
  -webkit-box-pack:center;
  -webkit-box-align:center;

  /* IE10 -Doesn't work! */
  display: -ms-box;
  -ms-box-orient:horizontal;
  -ms-box-pack:center;
  -ms-box-align:center;
}
```

This works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox.

But of course it doesn't work right in IE 10 (I haven't tested in older version of IE yet). The text stays at the top.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EeHEp)

Am I missing something?

Comment: No browser implements `display: box` and it should not be marked as *W3C*.  Those properties are all from an outdated draft.

Comment: display: box section has been removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works fine for me on IE 10. Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KtCjs/1/)
Screenshot: http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/9135/eae7aabb6f494aeb8410553.png

```
display: -ms-flexbox;
-ms-flex-align: center;
-ms-flex-pack: center;
-ms-box-orient:horizontal;
```

Comment: There is no `-ms-box-orient` property:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772069(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I don't know where you got it from, but it didn't come from me.

Comment: Nvm. I was editing your fiddle and forgot to remove that line. See its there in your code(second property).

Comment: Umm.. okay! Just noticed, [Adrift](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1783413/adrift) edited the post.

Comment: Specifically, -ms-flex-direction "Specifies the orientation in the layout of all child elements of the object". "row" seems to the the equivalent of "horizontal". See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16132975/vertical-center-text-using-ms-box-in-ie-10

Answer (score 5):

IE10 doesn't implement the 2009 Flexbox spec, it implements the draft from March 2012.

This should be what you need:

```
.foo {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -moz-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-flex-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  -webkit-flex-line-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
  -webkit-align-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}
```

I do have a collection of Sass mixins for Flexbox that handles all prefixes properly for you that you're free to use now:  https://gist.github.com/cimmanon/4461470.  They've been submitted to the Compass project and should be available in the next version.

Comment: How's that for a robust answer :D